# Create match group that matches string, or empty string, with re module sub()?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to manage a Calibre library. Calibre uses Python regex to manipulate database fields. In particular, you can specify the “pattern” and “repl” arguments to the sub() method. But that’s all you can do, no other coding. My current problem is that if there is no match for my group expression, Calibre reports an “unmatched group” error, and refuses to proceed.

Can I create a group that “always matches” but contains an empty string if it’s really not there?

I want to replace a field with a sub-string from the title, if the sub-string is found, or an empty string if it is not. I currently have mixed titles like:

```
Anne  McCaffrey - Pern 10 - The Renegades of Pern
Generation Warriors
The Mystery of Ireta: Dinosaur Planet & Dinosaur Planet Survivors
Anne McCaffrey - Tsw 7 - Ship That Returned
```

I want to pick out “Pern 10” from the first example, and “Tsw 7” from the fourth example, and write them to the series field. How can I do this?

My current, erroneous expression is

```
(((P<author>[^-]*?)- )?((?P<series>\w+)\W*(?P<series_index>\d*)\s-))?(?P<title>.*)
```

The only field I want at the moment is

```
\g<series>
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I don’t think it really uses the Perl `re` module, does it? I think it just uses Perl regexes. Are you thinking of the Python `re` module? I see you’re using the Python named capture syntax, which Perl does support, although per my comment below, I like the Java syntax better, myself.

Comment: [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) is a Python application. I fixed the description and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the requirements correctly, it sounds like you should be able to write:

```
^(?:(?! - ).)*(?: - )?(?P<series>(?:(?! - ).)*)
```

The initial `^(?:(?! - ).)*` part will swallow everything before the first space-hyphen-space — or simply swallow everything, if there is no space-hyphen-space.

The `(?: - )?` part will swallow the first space-hyphen-space if it's there, or otherwise nothing.

The `(?:(?! - ).)*` part inside the `(?P<series>...)` will swallow everything that hasn't already been swallowed, up until the second space-hyphen-space (or end-of-string, if no second space-hyphen-space is found). If everything has already been swallowed, then this will simply be the empty string.

In other words, the above is roughly equivalent to:

```
@parts = split $title, / - /, 3;
$series = ((@parts > 1) ? $parts[1] : '');
```

Will that work for you?

Comment: The `split` approach is much, much better than anything using far  more complicated patterns.

Comment: I’m sure you know this, but I find the `(?P<name>...)` syntax more cleanly written as `(?<name>...)`. Named capture groups have a lot of compatability syntax variants with other languages’ regex libraries, but me I’ve unified on the `(?<name>...)` and `\k<name>` style pairs.  Plus the “regex subroutine” calling syntax of `(?&name)` for pattern recursion. The Java 7 pattern library uses the `(?<name>...)` and `\k<name>` style, but doesn’t allow recursion.

Comment: Great! I only had to add a trailing ".*" to get it to work well enough. Thanks!